# Product images not load PWA setup magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, pwa

I had done a PWA setup on my local machine.

I am facing product and category images issue.
[image]

Images path :

```
src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAFCAQAAADIpIVQAAAADklEQVR42mNkgAJGIhgAALQABsHyMOcAAAAASUVORK5CYII="

src="/img/resize/300?url=%2Fmedia%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Fv%2Fs%2Fvsk12-la_main_3.jpg"
```

Comment: I have the same issue but only occurs when I start the PWA dev server with the yarn/npm watch command, I can see the images when I use the stage command. I think it's an issue with the SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this issue by copying the contents of `vendor/magento/sample-data-media-venia/catalog` to `pub/media/catalog`. Hope this helps.

Reference :
https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio/issues/413

Comment: I already tried this, but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Open this file

```
/var/www/html/magento231/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/.env
```

Remove comment and replace path like

```
# MAGENTO_BACKEND_MEDIA_PATH_PRODUCT="/media/catalog/product"
# MAGENTO_BACKEND_MEDIA_PATH_CATEGORY="/media/catalog/category"
```

To

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_MEDIA_PATH_PRODUCT="/pub/media/catalog/product"
MAGENTO_BACKEND_MEDIA_PATH_CATEGORY="/pub/media/catalog/category"
```